# Trouble assigning values to a structure

Tags: c, struct

I am using a loop and fgets to run through this input file

```
CSCI112 Programming with C 3
CSCI127 Joy and Beauty of Data 4
CSCI132 Basic Data Structures and Algorithms 4
CSCI338 Computer Science Theory 3
CSCI215 Social and Ethical Issues in CS 3
ARCH112 Introduction to Design 3
COMX112 Interpersonal Skills in the Workplace 1
HSTA101 American History 4
XXXXXXX XXXXXX X
```

I have to determine the number of CSCI classes(and other things, but those are not important). Currently, I am using a class structure that contains a string ID, a string name, and an int credits.

My problem is that in my array of classes, all the IDs are being stored as "XXXXXXX". I can't understand why the for loop is not properly assigning values to the class.

If I run the program the out put is

```
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-3
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-4
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-4
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-3
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-3
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-3
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-1
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX X, Credits-4
CSCI classes: 0
CSCI class credits: 0
```

Obviously the classes are not right and the CSCI numbers are wrong. I don't understand how the credits can be assigned properly but the ID and name are not?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "class.h"

int main(){

  //variable declaration for classes
  char line[100];
  char line_copy[100];
  char ccred;

  class_t classes[100];
  int i = 0;

  //infinite loop
  for(;;){

    //read in input from file
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    strcpy(line_copy, line);

    classes[i].ID = strtok(line, " ");
    classes[i].name = strtok(NULL, "1234");

    //remove trailing space from class name
    classes[i].name[strlen(classes[i].name) - 1] = 0;
    ccred = line_copy[strlen(line_copy) - 2];
    classes[i].credits = ccred - '0';

    //stop reading input if not a valid class
    if(strcmp(classes[i].ID, "XXXXXXX") == 0){
      break;
    }   
    i++;            
  }

  int ii;
  for(ii = 0; ii < i; ii++){
    printf("Class: ID-%s, ", classes[ii].ID);
    printf("Name-%s, ", classes[ii].name);
    printf("Credits-%d\n", classes[ii].credits);
  }

  //find CSCI classes and credits only
  int CSCIclasses = 0;
  int CSCIcredits = 0;
  char toCompare[] = "CSCI";
  int k; 
  for(k = 0; k < i; k++){
    if(strncmp(toCompare, classes[k].ID, 4) == 0){
      printf("CSCI course!");
      CSCIclasses++;
      CSCIcredits += classes[k].credits;
    }
  }

  printf("CSCI classes: %d\n", CSCIclasses);
  printf("CSCI class credits: %d\n", CSCIcredits);


  return 0;
}
```

My question is: how can I properly assign value to the class structure and get the proper number of CSCI classes and credits?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: strongly suggest using the call to `fgets()` to control the loop, similar to: `while( fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) ) {... }

Comment: the posted code is including a home grown header file: `class.h` but the contents of that file are not posted.  Please include the contents of that file.

Comment: the posted code is declaring an array of the struct class_t but does not include a definition of that struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function returns pointers to the buffer you're tokenizing. That means all `ID` and `name` pointers of *all* structures will point to the very same `line` array.

You could use dynamic allocation with `malloc` and then `strcpy` to copy the strings (or the common but non C standard `strdup` function). Or use arrays (and `strcpy`) for the string in the structure.

Comment: Could you explain how you would use arrays and strcpy? Wouldn't the array still have to go through the strtok?

Comment: @afccorbin If you're certain that the input is correct and that `strtok` will *never* return a null pointer, just `strcpy(classes[i].ID, strtok(line, " "))`. However, some error-checking and validation might be good to have, so e.g. `char *id = strtok(line, " "); if (id == NULL) { /* TODO: Handle error */ } strcpy(classes[i].ID, id);`

Comment: Thanks so much! I implemented it and it works! Just for my own understanding, when I do this I am copying the instantaneous VALUE of the token into the class.ID instead of the token's ADDRESS, which would change the contents of class.ID every time it goes back through the loop?

Answer (score 0):

While you now understand that `line` and any copy you make, or any pointer that refers to an address within `line` will point to the final contents in `line` at the end of your read loop, you may next run into issues attempting to tokenize each line due to the whitespace in the `name`.

While you can use `strtok`, saving each previous pointer from tokenizing on `'space'` and then use the previous pointer as the end pointer for `name`, it's a whole lot easier to simply use `strchr` to find the first space and `strrchr` to set a pointer to the nul-char (or use `strlen` to set a pointer to the end character) and then backup to find the last `'space'`. That way, you know everything between the first space and last space is `name`, and the character after the last space is `credits`. That makes it rather simple to handle.

Putting that altogether, you could do something like the following, using a fixed array for `credits` (you know that is 6-chars max) and allocating storage for `name`, and eliminating `line_copy` as walking a pointer down line, picking out what you need doesn't modify `line`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for malloc/free */
#include <string.h>
// #include "class.h"

#define MAXID   8       /* maximum ID, characters & structs   */
#define MAXC  128       /* if you need constants, define them */
#define MAXS MAXC       /*     (don't use magic numbers)      */

typedef struct {
    char ID[MAXID],     /* fixed 8 chars for 6 + 1 needed for ID */
        *name,          /* you must allocate storage for name */
        credits;
} class_t;

int main(){

    char line[MAXC] = "",       /* variable declaration for classes */
        *toCompare = "CSCI";    /* CSCI classes and credits only */
    int CSCIclasses = 0,    
        CSCIcredits = 0,
        i, n = 0;    
    size_t maxlen = 0;
    class_t classes[MAXS] = {{ .ID = "" }};

    for (; n < MAXS; ) {    /* loop continually for input */

        char *p = line,             /* pointer to line */
            *ep = NULL;             /* end pointer for line */

        if (!fgets (line, sizeof(line), stdin))  /* read/validate line */
            break;

        ep = strchr (line, ' ');   /* set end pointer to 1st space */

        if (ep) {                       /* validate 1st space found */
            size_t len = ep - p;        /* get length of ID */
            if (len > MAXID - 1) {      /* validate it fits + nul-char */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: ID exceeds MAXID.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            strncpy (classes[n].ID, p, len);    /* copy ID */
            classes[n].ID[len] = 0;     /* nul-terminate ID */
        }
        else
            continue;                   /* get next line */

        p = ep + 1;                     /* set pointer to start of name */
        ep = strrchr (line, 0);         /* set end pointer to nul-character */

        while (ep > p && *ep != ' ')    /* backup to last space */
            ep--;

        if (*ep == ' ') {           /* if space, parse remainder o fline */
            size_t len = ep - p;    /* len of name */
            if (!(classes[n].name = malloc (len + 1))) { /* allocate */
                perror ("malloc-classes[].name");
                break;
            }
            ep++;                   /* move end pointer to credits */
            strncpy (classes[n].name, p, len);  /* copy to name */
            classes[n].name[len] = 0;       /* nul-termiante name */
            if ('0' <= *ep && *ep <= '9')   /* is credits digit? */
                classes[n++].credits = *ep - '0'; /* assign credits */
            else
                classes[n++].credits = 0;   /* set credits zero */
            if (len > maxlen)
                maxlen = len;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)     /* output class information */
        printf ("Class: ID-%s, Name-%s, %-*s Credits-%d\n", classes[i].ID, 
                classes[i].name, (int)(maxlen - strlen(classes[i].name) + 1), 
                " ", classes[i].credits);
    putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with newline */

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {   /* output CSCI courses, free memory */
        if (strncmp (toCompare, classes[i].ID, 4) == 0) {
            printf("CSCI course! - %s\n", classes[i].name);
            CSCIclasses++;
            CSCIcredits += classes[i].credits;
        }
        free (classes[i].name); /* free 'name' - no longer needed */
    }

    printf ("CSCI classes: %d\n", CSCIclasses);     /* output CSCI summary */
    printf ("CSCI class credits: %d\n", CSCIcredits);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the definitions of constants. If you need one (or more) `#define` them or use an `enum` to do it. Don't sprinkle magic numbers like `100` all through your code. Define them at the top, so if your needs change, you have one simple place to make the change, and the rest is automatically handled)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/classes <dat/classes.txt
Class: ID-CSCI112, Name-Programming with C,                      Credits-3
Class: ID-CSCI127, Name-Joy and Beauty of Data,                  Credits-4
Class: ID-CSCI132, Name-Basic Data Structures and Algorithms,    Credits-4
Class: ID-CSCI338, Name-Computer Science Theory,                 Credits-3
Class: ID-CSCI215, Name-Social and Ethical Issues in CS,         Credits-3
Class: ID-ARCH112, Name-Introduction to Design,                  Credits-3
Class: ID-COMX112, Name-Interpersonal Skills in the Workplace,   Credits-1
Class: ID-HSTA101, Name-American History,                        Credits-4
Class: ID-XXXXXXX, Name-XXXXXX,                                  Credits-0

CSCI course! - Programming with C
CSCI course! - Joy and Beauty of Data
CSCI course! - Basic Data Structures and Algorithms
CSCI course! - Computer Science Theory
CSCI course! - Social and Ethical Issues in CS
CSCI classes: 5
CSCI class credits: 17
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.